# Passing a file with multiple patterns to grep

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, grep

Let's say we have two files.

**match.txt**: A file containing patterns to match:

```
fed ghi
tsr qpo
```

**data.txt**: A file containing lines of text:

```
abc fed ghi jkl
mno pqr stu vwx
zyx wvu tsr qpo
```

Now, I want to issue a grep command that should return the first and third line from **data.txt**:

```
abc fed ghi jkl
zyx wvu tsr qpo
```

... because each of these two lines match one of the patterns in **match.txt**.

I have tried:

```
grep -F -f match.txt data.txt
```

but that returns no results.

grep info: GNU grep 2.6.3 (cygwin)
OS info: Windows 2008 R2

**Update**: It seems, that grep is confused by the space in the search pattern lines, but with the -F flag, it should be treating each line in **match.txt** as an individual match pattern.

Comment: Which OS are you using, exactly?  I see this is tagged Windows, but I've not found the Windows version of grep to be very feature-filled.

Comment: Question updated with all version info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is as follows:

Use the command: `tr -d "\r" <match.txt | grep -F -f - text.txt`

It seems that `grep` does not correctly respect windows line endings (CR/LF) for match files presented to it via the -f flag. The `tr` command can be used to strip carriage returns from the match file and the - special flag can be used with `grep`, to force it to read the match file from standard input.

Comment: Worth noting that in any typical git/hg version control workflow where you treat the pattern file as a text file and some users are on Windows, stripping carriage returns like this will be necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works on Unix, perhaps you need a later version of grep?

```
>cat d
abc fed ghi jkl
mno pqr stu vwx
zyx wvu tsr qpo

>cat p
fed ghi
tsr qpo

>grep -F -f p d
abc fed ghi jkl
zyx wvu tsr qpo
```

what happens if you change the patterns to

```
fed\040ghi
tsr\040qpo
```

Comment: I have found a solution, and am posting it as an answer to my own question. It has nothing to do with the version of grep.